# mouseover on a image map to display another image map

Tags: javascript, html, imagemap

I am a beginner trying to learn `html` and `javascript`, so please be patient.

I have a problem on which I have been stuck for a while.
I have page with a `top` image map with 3 different `areas` that should display 3 different new `image maps` according to which area of `top` is hovered. 
So far I can display a new image when one of those `area` is hovered, here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">

var img = document.createElement("img");

    function showDetails(id) {
    var secondRow = document.getElementById("shopTable").rows[1];

switch(id){
case 1: 
    img.src = "pics/pic1.png";
    secondRow.appendChild(img); 
    break;
case 2:
    img.src = "pics/pic2.png";
    secondRow.appendChild(img);
    break;
case 3:
    img.src = "pics/pic3.png";
    secondRow.appendChild(img);
    break;      
default: break;}
    }
 </SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
    <table id = "shopTable">
        <tr>
            <td><map name="samplemap">
                <area href = "#" coords = "7,140,85,180" shape ="rect"  onMouseOver = "showDetails(1)"></area>
                <area href= "#" coords = "100,140,182,180" shape="rect" onMouseOver="showDetails(2)"></area>
                <area href= "#" coords = "196,140,276,180" shape="rect" onMouseOver="showDetails(3)"></area>

            </map></td>

            <img name = "top" usemap = "#samplemap" src="pics/top.png"></img>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                                <!-- here goes my image that should be an imagemap -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

So now I in the second cell of the `table` I am displaying pictures(either `pic1, pic2, pic 3`), but what I want to do is to display `image maps`. So, for instance, if user hovers on the first `area` of `top` I want to display a imagemap that uses `pic1` and so on. 
Could anybody help me out on this?
Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: where are the three others <map name="..."> and why you don't set the img.useMap = '#oneOfTheThreeMap' ?

Comment: @progysm thank you for your time, where should I put the three maps? all of them inside the second cell?

Comment: somewhere in the body, map is not visible

Comment: @progysm yep it's working, pretty straight forward. Thanx!